# Flutter: How to convert AssetImage to Unit8List?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am trying to insert to a SQFlite database a webp image that I have in my assets.
But I don't know how to convert the asset image to a Uint8List which is the data type in my DB.
How can I do it?

I have tried this:

```
Future<Uint8List> convert() async {
 final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/ab.webp');
 final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
 return list;
}

Uint8List list = convert();
```

But I get the following error:
Type: Future Function()

A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Uint8List'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Uint8List'.

Thank you in advance

Comment: how do you use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert()` is a async function so when you want to use it you should await for the result and also your convert function does not rerturn any thing.

try this:

```
Future<Uint8List> convert() async {
 final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image.webp');
 final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
 return list;
}
```

then use it like this:

```
Uint8List list = await convert();
```

Comment: where did you call Uint8List list = await convert() ?

Comment: I have moved it to an asyn function and it works correctly, thank you very much eamiroh3in

Comment: Glad to hear that. If it helps you please accept and up vote it so makes it easier to find by other people. more information (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I can't yet because it's my first question and I have to earn the "reputation", but as soon as I have it I'll do it :)